# Centered div with images left and right which should go beyond browser window

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I have a website with a centered fixed width div (the div is centered using margin-left: auto). Now I want to show to the left and right of this div some images. The images should not affect the scrolling of the browser window. If the resolution is too small the images should be cut off, without showing a scrollbar in the browser.  But if there is not enough space for the centered div a scrollbar should appear.

How can this be achieved?

Edit: Site without images on the left / right is available here: http://b-sides.ch/openair12/

Comment: Without any code or a link to a site we can't be of much help, but try adding `overflow-x: hidden` to either `<body>` or `<html>`.

Comment: website is available here (without the images left / right): http://b-sides.ch/openair12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would put images as a background of the page (body background) as a single jpg. Keep a space between the images that is equal the width of your centered div.
But maybe you should show your code.

Comment: Thanks! background image might be a solution. But since the centered div is 1250px width, this would be quite a waste of bandwidth. Site (without image is available here: http://b-sides.ch/openair12/)

Answer (score 0):

For your problem i suggest you start making the site fluid. And then apply media queries to get rid off the 'sidebars' when the screen gets smaller. 
In the media query you tell the browser to get a

```
overflow-x:scroll;
```

Here is a site with nice examples for making your site fluid and still compatible in all browsers: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this solves my case. The images should also be show if they don't completely fit to the screen (They are just decorative to fill bigger resolutions.